# Get value from nested tag for XML contain in string

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodes

I'm trying to read value from nested tag from an XML and having trouble with it.

My XML file called *NewFile.xml*  I'm trying read the value in tag4.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <tag1>
        <tag2>
            <tag3>
                <tag4>read me</tag4>
            </tag3>
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
```

Here is a main class called *Test.java* which reads that XML file and coverts it to string and sends it the the method called lookUpValue in reader class.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, XPathExpressionException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("NewFile.xml")));
        String xmlString;   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((xmlString=br.readLine())!= null){
            sb.append(xmlString.trim());
        }

        xmlString = sb.toString();

        System.out.print(reader.LookUpValue(xmlString));
        br.close();
    }   
}
```

Here is the reader class and the method LookupValue:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class reader{

    public static String LookUpValue(String sb) throws XPathExpressionException
    {   
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(sb));
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Object customer = xpath.evaluate("/tag1/tag2/tag3", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
        String value = xpath.evaluate("tag4", customer);

        return ("Value is: " + value);
    }
}
```

My question is how can I read the value inside tag4 right now when I run this program I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:275)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:365)
    at reader.LookUpValue(LookUpValue.java:21)
    at test.main(test.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:212)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:335)
    ... 5 more
---------
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:212)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:335)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:275)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:365)
    at reader.LookUpValue(LookUpValue.java:21)
    at test.main(test.java:26)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:365)
    at reader.LookUpValue(LookUpValue.java:21)
    at test.main(test.java:26)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:275)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:212)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(XPath.java:335)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Yes customer is coming out null Idk why is that...

Comment: when I print out xmlString it printers out this `<?xml version="1.0"?><tag1><tag2><tag3><tag4>read me</tag4></tag3></tag2></tag1>`  which is the right value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Reader {
    public static String lookUpValues(String sb) throws Exception{  

        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource src = new InputSource();
        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(sb));

        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
        String value = doc.getElementsByTagName("tag4").item(0).getTextContent();
        
        return value;
    }
}
```